Do not see logs out of signalr server app on azure
I've got signalrserver deployed on azure portal. It receives and sends back messages against connected clients. The problem is i do not see any logs out of ILogger. What could be the reason? Note that I enabled logs in App Service log.
I was looking at azure portal at Log stream section and none of my ILogger _logger msgs are shown, i have also checked via cli:
az webapp log tail --name MySignalRApp1 --resource-group MyResourceGroup   

Please also note that that ive tried with basic Console.Writeline besides ILogger and it also doesn't print out any logs on azure.
What have i missed?
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Services.AddLogging();


builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];
});

builder.Logging.AddConsole();  
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();  

builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["AzureSignalRConnectionString"];
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"); 
app.Run();

ChatHub: (shortened)
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILogger<ChatHub> _logger;

    public ChatHub(ILogger<ChatHub> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Connect(string username)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Test_1");
        _logger.LogDebug($"Test_2");
        _logger.LogTrace($"Test_3");
    }
}


Are you able to see the other logs in Application Insights?

@PravallikaKV Where exactly to look? Currently i am checking "Log stream" section.

Check my answer below.

I have used below code to log the Ilogger and SignalR service related logs in Azure Application Insights.
Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(
    options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["AzureSignalRConnectionString"];
    });
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights(
        configureTelemetryConfiguration: (config) =>
            config.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"],
            configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { }
    );
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapHub<ChatSampleHub>("/chat");
app.Run();

You can add the Ilogger messages in a separate method.
ChatSampleHub.cs:
public class ChatSampleHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILogger<ChatSampleHub> _logger;

    public ChatSampleHub(ILogger<ChatSampleHub> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation("Test_1");
        _logger.LogDebug("Test_2");
        _logger.LogTrace("Test_3");
    }

    public Task BroadcastMessage(string name, string message) =>
        Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", name, message);

    public Task Echo(string name, string message) =>
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId)
                .SendAsync("echo", name, $"{message} (echo from server)");
}

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://signalR.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=9UF4GqEanyXXXQt1;Version=1.0;",
  "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=f8acXXXX"
}

Console logs:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7098
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5114
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\WebApplication3
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[20]
      Service connection 3eb723e9-XX225-b93a-507b6eb78b72 connected.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[20]
      Service connection 776f3fab-44XX-a760-c49377e5c382 connected.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[20]
      Service connection 5cab944XX84-4eeb-8ee4-df866b25ae39 connected.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[20]
      Service connection fc56ebda-88e2-465c-99c4-b77f4a6f7dd1 connected.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[20]
      Service connection d87b9b26-da4b-438b-a473-fbffced9782f connected.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.StrongServiceConnectionContainer[1]
      Hub 'ChatSampleHub' is now connected to '(Primary)https://signalR.service.signalr.net(hub=ChatSampleHub)'.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.NegotiateHandler[0]
      Use default handshake timeout.
info: ChatSampleHub[0]
      Test_1
info: ChatSampleHub[0]
      Test_1
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceLifetimeManager[0]
      Start to broadcast message 543904857XX70528.
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.MultiEndpointMessageWriter[11]
      Route message 54390XX0070528 to service endpoint (Primary)https://signalR.service.signalr.net(hub=ChatSampleHub).
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceLifetimeManager[110]
      Succeeded to send message 543904XX0070528.


Select Verbose as LogLevel under App Service=>App Service Logs



You can see the ILogger messages in LogStream of Azure App Service.


Application Insights:

You can check the logs under App Service=>Monitoring=>Application Insights=>Investigate=>Transaction Search:


You can also check the logs under Application Insights=>Overview=>Logs:

You can debug the code locally and check if you are hitting the Ilogger code Connect method in your ChatHub class.
